# Copy information from iframe to document

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to copy information from an iframe to my document, I wrote this

```
<iframe class="Number" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true">

     <html>
         <body id="wow">002-7375347
              </body>
    </html>

</iframe>


html = $("iframe").find("body").html();
document.write(html);
```

and it doesn't work can somebody help me? 
Thank you.

Comment: Check your title, do you mean copy FROM iframe to document? Is your goal to retrieve the contents of the body tag from your iframe and use them in the page where the iframe exists? Please explain more clearly.

Comment: Are they on the same domain and subdomain?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I've never seen anyone doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this if the iframe and the document running your javascript have the same `origin` (same domain, port, protocol, a few other things). This is a security feature called the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) implemented by all major browsers. You cannot really get around it.

The rationale for this feature is to prevent the following (greatly simplified) scenario.

1. You go to untrusted site blahblah.com
2. The site creates an invisible`iframe` and points it to your Amazon home page.
3. You are logged in with the credentials from your browser and blahblah.com goes on to steal all your personal information.

The policy as implemented is broadly summed up as

> Requests from one origin can execute code from another origin and display it, but cannot programmatically manipulate nor examine their contents.

So your code can

- Open an `iframe` but not be able to examine its contents
- Include images from google on your page but not be able to read the pixels or send the image back to the server
- Execute a script from the Google.com cdn but not be able to view anything that code is doing nor be able to get the code itself as a string.

Exploiting the fact that this is somewhat different to program correctly is a large part of what web hackers do.

Comment: Thank you. but it's running from the same domain?

Comment: Check the definition of the origin, its more than just the domain, it has to be the same website pretty much. Do all of those line up?